# Can ふんいき and かんじ mean the same thing?

Tags: word-choice

I am using online chats to study, and I wanted to convey a good feeling about the chat. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... You meant to ask "Can ふんいき and **かんじ** mean the same thing?", no? 「[感]{かん}じ」(noun 'feeling'), not 「[感]{かん}じ**る** 」(verb 'feel')

Comment: ＠shoko, yes, a good feeling.

Comment: かんじ Just means feeling. いい感じ then means good feeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

雰囲気{ふんいき} is a noun meaning atmosphere and 感{かん}じる is the verb to feel. 感じ then means feeling (with 良{よ}い感じ meaning good feeling).